# How to fix browser-sync-webpack-plugin

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

After updating project to new version, I need to update my npm. At this moment I want to install npm but when I run "npm i or npm install" I face to following Error.

In addition I run "npm i --force" but This command did not solve my problem either.

Can you help me to resolve this problem ?
I use laravel 9 for this project.

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.0.1
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.44.2
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     dev babel-loader@"^8.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!     babel-loader@"^8.0.4" from laravel-mix@4.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/laravel-mix
npm ERR!       dev laravel-mix@"^4.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (laravel-mix-svg-sprite)
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@1.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!     css-loader@"^1.0.1" from laravel-mix@4.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/laravel-mix
npm ERR!       dev laravel-mix@"^4.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (laravel-mix-svg-sprite)
npm ERR!     peer css-loader@"*" from vue-loader@15.9.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/vue-loader
npm ERR!       vue-loader@"^15.4.2" from laravel-mix@4.1.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/laravel-mix
npm ERR!         dev laravel-mix@"^4.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!         1 more (laravel-mix-svg-sprite)
npm ERR!   15 more (dotenv-webpack, extract-text-webpack-plugin, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^1 || ^2 || ^3" from browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/browser-sync-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev browser-sync-webpack-plugin@"2.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@3.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^1 || ^2 || ^3" from browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/browser-sync-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     dev browser-sync-webpack-plugin@"2.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/zelda/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm worried that this package is no longer supported and we'll have to migrate to an alternative. However, I've tried several alternatives and haven't found one satisfactory.